# Неопределённость в версиях

Tags: java, maven, version

Я писал код на 15.0.2 jdk и использовал её функциональность. Используя Maven, автоматизировал свой проект. На выходе получил готовый jar файл. Всё хорошо. Cложность возникла в том, что у другого пользователя лишь jre 1.8.0, соответственно выявляется несовместимость. Нужно ли пользователю устанавливать выше версию или как-то можно
без этого обойтись? (IDE:Eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ваш код собирался и запускался как 1.8 нужно добавить в `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Но писать надо будет тоже как на 1.8